# Maven archetype: Generate error

Tags: apache, maven, command-prompt

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

produces

The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...

```
    1.directory is C://Program Files/Apache-maven-3.2.5
    2.I see the directory in the command line so i know it's there
    3.tried running as administrator, safe mode, tried Apache-maven 3.0.5 as well
    4.Maybe incredibly simple but any help is appreciated, thx.
```

Comment: check if you have maven in your system , by using `mvn --version`

Comment: He was right maven was connecting b/c of error in environment variables.

Comment: A good guide that got  me through was http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm.  Thank you Subham Tripathi, you got me going in the right direction.

Comment: pleasure is mine ! :)